# How to inspect element in IOS app on iphone?

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am quite new to IOS app automation testing.
I am trying to automate the testing of IOS app using Appium.
But I am not able to inspect the element of IOS app on simulator.
I am using a

- Mac Book Pro 10.14.2 version,
- 'xcode' V10.1,
- npm version 6.5.0,
- node v11.6.0,
- Simulator iPhone 8 V12.1,
- Appium version 1.9.1,
- Mobile platform version 12.1.

The Appium install and the App and the WDA started on the simulator,
but after that, it failed to start the application.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using official inspector tool: **[appium-desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop)**

First of all, you need to resign WebDriverAgent with Apple developer certificate you are using for your iOS app.

Then launch appium-desktop and start a new session with following capabilities:

```
app: <absolute path to ipa file>
automationName: 'XCUITest'
deviceName: 'iPhone X'
platformName: 'iOS'
platformVersion: '11.0',
udid: <your device UDID>,
xcodeOrgId:
xcodeSigningId:
```

More details about Appium [capabilities in general](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/) and [iOS XCUITest ones](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver#desired-capabilities).

Comment: But i am installing the app on simulator. Do i still need xcodeOrgId & xcodeSigningId? Also with the appium desktop, i am able to install WDA agent & my app on simulator, but app failed to launch the app. I also tried to manually install the WDA agent on the simulator, but cant figure out that has it been installed or not. It logged following info and stuck there.

xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination id=5C024B5F-4B34-4F58-BECF-7A1D90115B3C test

Comment: You don't need those caps for simulator, but you need to sign WDA with Apple dev account to allow it launch your application. Follow the instructions  and provide full stacktrace to get more help

Comment: Thanks for your reply dmle. Finally i was able to run WDA & my application on physical device, I am still facing issue in case of simulator, but i hope i will be able to sort that out.